# Which one of these DS18B20 temperature sensors is fake?

Tags: sensor, temperature

A while back I bought two DS18B20 for half price, and today I bought another one for double the price. The part number on the cheaper one is printed while on the expensive one it's laser etched:

[image]

*On the left is the expensive one.*

Even though the price was double, the readings that I'm getting using Arduino are the same:

[image]

*Sensor1 is the expensive one. While the temperature on mercury thermometer was 23.9-ish degrees.*

So what's the difference? Why is the build quality and price different but the temperature readings are the same?

Comment: What makes you think one is fake? You paid whatever they asked, it doesn't make it a fair price.

Comment: @Finbarr just because of the build quality...

Comment: They look pretty similar to me. A better photo might help though. Manufacturers do change their assembly and printing machinery from time to time.

Comment: @Finbarr the cheaper one is shiny but the other one isn't, it does look cheap though. definitely looks like something from china market. what wonders me is the temperature reading, which is the same!

Comment: Strange that they are marked "Dallas", since Dallas Semiconductor was acquired by Maxim Integrated in 2001. https://www.maximintegrated.com/DS18B20 -- I'll never understand why people insist on buying from shady grey market vendors when Maxim sells factory direct and even gives free samples upon request!  *(Full disclosure: I work at Maxim)*

Comment: @MarkU but all images of DS18B20 in google search is marked with "DALLAS"! do you have/seen any of this sensors without DALLAS mark?

Comment: @MarkU sorry i didn't see your comment edit "*(Full disclosure: I work at Maxim)*", so the original ones should have MAXIM mark on them instead of DALLAS. right?

Comment: No, the original ones were made by Dallas while Dallas Semiconductor was a separate company. I see no reason to believe that either of these devices is a fake, nor do I see any evidence that either of them is genuine. You have to use a trusted supply chain.

Comment: Some suspect-source (stainless probe encapsulated) parts seem to convert much more slowly than the data sheet says they should.  That said, there is also Arduino code floating around that horribly mis-operates, getting the adjustment for various bit resolutions backwards - and you might hit that, because one way of dealing with a slow sensor is to read it at a lower resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There isn't any good way to know.** As Elliot Alderson rightly points out, both could be legitimate, or both could be fake.

- If the packaging and marking are different between the two parts, that could simply be because the manufacturer changed their packaging process. You'd have to check product change notices to confirm.
- The price difference could simply be because "each vendor charged the highest amount they could get away with". (The fact that you bought the parts indicates that this strategy worked.)
- Again from Elliot Alderson, the only way you can really trust a part is if you *trust the supply chain*. Otherwise the part could be counterfeit, or even if it's not counterfeit it could have been subjected to poor handling practices or similar. It sounds like the supply chain wasn't trusted in either of these cases, so each part should only be trusted to the degree that you have tested it.

Here is a [nice presentation from Xtreme Semiconductor, a company that specializes in detecting counterfeit parts](http://www.xtremesemi.com/pdf/DMSMS2011_Avoiding_Counterfeit_Components.pdf). Slides 20-31 show some examples of the tricks people pull when making counterfeit parts. Some are easy to detect with the unaided eye, others require advanced tricks like X-ray or opening up the part, as shown in the same slide set. Probably not something you're looking to do here.

**tl;dr Just because the parts look different and were priced differently doesn't necessarily mean that one is good and/or one is fake. Put the part through rigorous testing, or just buy a new part from a trusted source.**

Answer (score 11):

After purchasing many DS18B20 sensors and probes on ebay I can assure you that price is a useless indicator for quality.

Let me address the question in the title of this thread: **Which one of these DS18B20 temperature sensors is fake?**

Fortunately, you can find out for yourself: you cannot proof that a part is authentic but if it behaves differently from an authentic, Maxim-produced DS18B20 then it is certainly a fake.

After looking at some hundreds of DS18B20 and comparing them to chips that are known to be produced by Maxim Integrated I concluded that the manufacturers of counterfeit DS18B20 do not bother to conceal the fact that they're counterfeit. They just try to make them look and act authentic *enough* to be able to sell them.

Based on that conjecture, try this:

1. Does the part have a ROM code that matches the pattern `28-xx-xx-xx-xx-00-00-xx`? If not, then it is not Maxim-produced. (Manufacturers of counterfeit parts seem to go to some length to make sure the ROM codes of their chips do not collide with the ROM codes of Maxim's or other producers' chips.)
2. In the scratchpad register, look at byte 6 (reserved and value not specified in current datasheets. It reads `0x0c` right after power-up and before the first temperature conversion -- if it doesn't even read `0x0c` right after power-up then your part is definitely a fake). If this byte does *not change* following `44h` temperature conversion commands even though the temperature reading changes then your DS18B20 is not produced by Maxim. (Background: Byte 6 is used in the DS18S20 to get 12-bit temperature resolution, and the DS18B20 and DS18S20 share the same circuit to the maximum extent possible, see detailed description in [Maxim Application Note 4377](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/4/4377.html).)
3. There are many other ways to tell, e.g. you can look for implementation bugs, implementation detail (e.g. the amount of time it takes to actually perform a temperature conversion), or response to undocumented function codes. I've summarized a bunch of differences I came across here: https://github.com/cpetrich/counterfeit_DS18B20

Alternatively,

- Ask Maxim tech support if the combination of date code and batch code printed on the chip exists in their database.

Comment: I noticed just now that you are the guy who published the data I posted in my own answer! Thanks for your work! Very appreciated!

Comment: Maybe of interest to you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512236/why-are-pins-in-my-esp8266-getting-damaged

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Chris for his testing and counterfeit detection sketches!

Maybe the attached graph of the readings from four sensors I purchased from a Chinese supplier on eBay plus one genuine Maxim DS18B20 (bought from a reputable distributor) will answer the question.

All five sensors are at the same temperature. It's pretty easy to see which is the genuine part. You can make your own minds up whether you can rely on the readings from the counterfeits.

[image: DS18B20 genuine vs. counterfeit readings]

Comment: Check the datasheet and see if there are a and b designations or packages, also check the output specs

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2020, you can know with good accuracy. The accepted answer is not completely correct anymore.

All the information is provided in https://github.com/cpetrich/counterfeit_DS18B20 which also links to Arduino sketches which can tell you, based on the expected data returned by the chip, whether your sensor is original or not. The clones do not fully respect the datasheet.

Basically, for the easiest check, if the ROM does not follow the pattern 28-xx-xx-xx-xx-00-00-xx then the DS18B20 sensor is a clone. Using the ROM code you can also find information about the issues with that specific clone.

Most if not all ds18b20 not bought by Digikey or equivalent suppliers are clones.