# Why are pins in my ESP8266 getting damaged?

Tags: esp8266, troubleshooting

I designed a circuit and a PCB to connect a relay, a switch, a Modbus-to-serial and two sets of DS18B20 to a ESP8266, specifically ESP-12F, to be controlled via ESPhome. The power is provided by a AC-DC 5 V converter, followed by a low dropout linear regulator. The two sets of DS18B20 are about 3 m and 7 m long, each one using a different pin of the ESP8266.

See schematics and image of the board. R1 and R2 are around 4-4.3 kohm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since I made a mistake in the width of the traces, I provided wires for the GND and 3.3 V for some components.

While the board won't win any prize (I even inverted the order of the names of the ESP8266 pins), it was working fine, so I **disconnected relay and switch** for practical reasons and then I let it run for few hours. Then one string of temperature sensors stopped working.

I checked the connections, the pullup resistor, the continuity, and at the end I connected the sensor to a different pin of the ESP8266 (you can see it from the rear side). It worked again, but it failed not long afterwards. The same for the other set of temperature sensors.

Today I found by chance [a study](https://github.com/cpetrich/counterfeit_DS18B20) according to which all my DS18B20 are counterfeit, mostly from family D according to the link provided. I ordered new ones from Digikey.

However, according to the study I linked, fake chips are characterised by poor performances, they should not damage the pins of the ESP8266.

Are there are other issues with my circuit, besides the fake sensors, which could damage the pins of the ESP8266?

Comment: What do the relays do? Are they switching? Are you sure that the ESP can provide enough current to switch the relay without getting damaged?

Comment: @FelixS Sorry, the relay works and it was not connected. The power is provided by a separate connection. Also, the relay has optocouplers and is active-low.

Comment: The DS18B20 seems to have the ability to charge a capacitor over the data line ("parasitic power supply"). With the long cables between sensor and ESP, I could imagine that there are voltage or current spikes on the data line. Maybe connect a resistor in series with the data line at the ESP.

Comment: Where's the 3.3 volt regulator? Where are your power supply decoupling capacitors?

Comment: IO4 and IO5 are wired differently... Typically you'd want 10K-ish pull-ups on any pin that needs it, like the EN, RST, and IO0. As Andy aka points out, you need some supply decoupling caps near the power pins on the ESP.

Comment: @FelixS even if the relay was not connected thanks for pointing it out, I just realized that relay+esp8266 actively transmitting at max power are very close to the rated output of the AC-DC module I used. Regarding the parasitic power: that requires Vcc tied to ground, which is not my case (TEMP1/2 connector, pin 1 is data, pin 2 is 3.3V, pin 4 is ground). I'm using normal power. Since the chips act as capacitor, a resistor on the data line produces a low-pass filter. I'll see if 100 ohm give problems or not.

Comment: @Andyaka the regulator is the TS1086. I omitted the decoupling caps because I thought that the electrolytic were close enough. I'll add them 1) to each onewire string 2) to the esp8266 3) one or two near the sensor themselves along the string. 10 nF should be good for the sensors, 1 uF for the ESP 8266, all plastic film.

Comment: @RomBeyer IO4 and IO5 are wired identically. They have a 4.7k pullup to 3.3V as specified in the datasheet, see R1 R2. I think RST and EN already have weak pull-ups internally (see also https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=7057 ), and IO0 is tied directly to 3.3V.

Comment: @FarO When you look at the diagram in the DS18B20 datasheet, you'll see that the data line and Vcc are both charging the capacitor over a diode. So even if you don't have Vcc connected to GND, the cap will draw current from the data line when the voltage drops on Vcc.

Comment: @FelixS I'll put the resistor which would help also with signal reflections, but wouldn't the data pin be set as high impedance by the firmware? I don't know how ESPhome works, but I used to set data pins as high impedance when I coded for AVR chips, even before Arduino.

Comment: @FarO Oh, is it only used as an input pin? I thought you had to send some kind of addressing to the sensors before they reply with the temperature. When transmitting on the pin, it can't be high impedance

Comment: @FelixS true, it can't be only high impedance

Comment: @FelixS still how come no one else in the Internet appears to have experienced this issue? I mean, counterfeit DS18B20 are quite common and ESP8266 too. I couldn't find anyone with damaged pins. I hope the decoupling on the ESP8266 and the original sensors will solve the issue.

Comment: @FarO well your setup is just especially vulnerable. The ESP isn't soldered properly, so you have a lot of excess parasitic inductance. Then you have the buck converter pretty close to it all, no proper power supply decoupling and you have very long cables to the sensor. All of that makes me think it's some kind of parasitics/EMI problem. And since it seems to be localised to only the ADC input, it sounds like that's where the damage is done.

Comment: @FelixS except for the ADC input, which is not used because the DS18B20 is digital and I'm using normal GPIO pins, the rest makes sense. Thanks